# Moving a Sprite in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm currently working on a school project, but I'm stuck trying to get my sprite to move.  My error message is saying that I'm missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in Mario.handle_keys().

Here's my main code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import*
from Mario import Mario
from Ladder import Ladder

pygame.init()
b = Mario([0, 800])
c = Ladder([600, 800])
game_over = False
dispwidth = 600
dispheight = 800
cellsize = 10
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
bg = white


def main():
    FPS = 30
    while not game_over:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        Mario.handle_keys()

        Mario.draw(screen)
        screen.fill(bg)
        screen.blit(b.image, b.rect)
        screen.blit(c.image, c.rect)
        pygame.display.update()
        fpstime.tick(FPS)

while True:
    global fpstime
    global screen

    fpstime = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((dispwidth, dispheight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Donkey Kong')
    main()
```

And my sprite:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*


class Mario(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image = None

    def __init__(self, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        if Mario.image is None:

            Mario.image = pygame.image.load('mario3.png')
        self.image = Mario.image

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottomleft = location

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def handle_keys(self):

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys_pressed[K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= 5

        if keys_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
            self.y += 5

    def draw(self, surface):

        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
```

Thanks in advance.

I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mario` is a class.  The method `handle_keys(self)` is an instance method -- meaning it can only be called against an `Mario` instance.  (It is possible to have a `classmethod`, but that's not what you want here since you need to modify `self`.)

At the top you made a `b = Mario([0, 800])` -- I'd change `b` to `mario` everywhere and `c` to `ladder`.

```
 mario = Mario([0, 800])
```

Then instead of `Mario.handle_keys()` you would use `mario.handle_keys()`.

More background:

When you call `mario.handle_keys()` what is actually happening underneath is more or less `handle_keys(mario)`.  The object `mario` ends up being the argument `self`.  Since you are attempting to call `handle_keys` on the class `Mario` instead, Python is complaining that nothing is being passed to `handle_keys` for the `self` parameter.

More off into the weeds:

If you define a class method, you would do it like this:

```
class Foo():
    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls):
        ...
```

You would call it `Foo.my_class_method()`, which would pass `Foo` to `my_class_method` as the `cls` parameter.

Comment: That helped but I've come to a new error.  Now it's telling me I'm missing 1 required positional argument: 'location' in __init__().  Any advice?

Comment: Depends on whose __init__() it is.  Probably you should just replace `b = Mario([0, 800])` with `mario = Mario([0, 800])`, or call `b.handle_keys()`

Comment: Thanks. That really helped.